# How do I tell polymer-ide where my public directory is?

Tags: polymer, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I'm trying out polymer-ide (in vscode, I had the same problem in atom) to lint my mixed html/js/css code.

The first error I get:

`[polymer-ide] Unable to load import: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jim/development/myproject/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'`

Each of my components imports an absolute path, like this:

`<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">`

bower_components, and all of the other 'public' code in my project are in a 'public' directory, so the path it should be looking for imports in is:

`'/Users/jim/development/myproject/public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'`

I understand that I could use relative references throughout my code, but that is at odds with refactoring and doing that throughout my project would be a 'tail-wagging-dog' situation.

There *should* be a way to tell polymer-ide that my content is hosted from a different location in the file system.  Ideally, I need to give it multiple mount points as I break things down into packages and each package might be in a different location.

I don't see any documentation for configuring polymer-ide.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Polymer ide uses `polymer.json` to configure internally to obtain file and folder structure to build and other configurations. But I don't think that will solve your issues because there's no way you can tell polymer to use this path settings.

I also found that using `source` in polymer.json will useful only when build. Closet way is to refactor your code. And use this...

```
<link rel="import" href="/public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

May be this not related with OP question but I need to make point here.

---

If your all polymer project files are inside the public including polymer.json you can run the project outside of the public/ directory with  --root option

```
polymer serve --root public/
```

Comment: I tried this, but it really screws up any attempt at encapsulating modules and REST APIs.  My old method relied on mounting public files at the same level as the REST APIs, so html imports could reference local URLs.  Now I need to have all of my modules have awareness of where they are mounted.

This is really the tail wagging the dog.  For want of better linting I am modifying my code in a way that is less encapsulated.  Not good.